# Subtitle in GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

We are trying to put a subtitle to a plot in GGPLOT2, but it should have different parts, like in "cat" function (`Trend: 54 %`), and the `Trend` part and the `%` symbol are always the same, but the `54` depends on a variable. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `paste` function.

Using your example:

```
value <- 54
paste("Trend: ", value, "%", sep="")

[1] "Trend: 54%"
```

And then you can put this into you ggplot subtitle:

```
ggplot(data=data) + labs(subtitle=paste("Trend: ", value, "%", sep=""))
```